# ImportError from using the trading strategy in PyAlgoTrade tutorial

Tags: python, pyalgotrade

I got an import error while I am running a simple python written trading strategy in Pyalgotrade.

```
from pyalgotrade.tools import yahoofinance
yahoofinance.download_daily_bars('orcl', 2000, 'orcl-2000.csv')

from pyalgotrade import strategy
from pyalgotrade.barfeed import yahoofeed
from pyalgotrade.technical import ma


class MyStrategy(strategy.BacktestingStrategy):
    def __init__(self, feed, instrument):
        strategy.BacktestingStrategy.__init__(self, feed)
        # We want a 15 period SMA over the closing prices.
        self.__sma = ma.SMA(feed[instrument].getCloseDataSeries(), 15)
        self.__instrument = instrument

    def onBars(self, bars):
        bar = bars[self.__instrument]
        self.info("%s %s" % (bar.getClose(), self.__sma[-1]))

# Load the yahoo feed from the CSV file
feed = yahoofeed.Feed()
feed.addBarsFromCSV("orcl", "orcl-2000.csv")

# Evaluate the strategy with the feed's bars.
myStrategy = MyStrategy(feed, "orcl")
myStrategy.run()
```

And the error is showed as below.

```
>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/johnhenry/Desktop/pyalgotrade2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyalgotrade import strategy
   File "/Users/johnhenry/Desktop/pyalgotrade.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyalgotrade import strategy
   ImportError: cannot import name strategy
```

I am sure I have this library called pyalgotrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named your *own* program `pyalgotrade.py`:

```
File "/Users/johnhenry/Desktop/pyalgotrade.py"
```

so Python thinks that's the one you mean.  Rename your program to something else, delete any `pyalgotrade.pyc` or `pyalgotrade.pyo` files you may have, and restart your interpreter.